# ElasticSearch - Run terms aggregation that returns terms that ONLY exist in document set A and NOT document set B

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to determine if what I'm trying to achieve is possible with ElasticSearch.

I have 2 sets of documents, lets say they are documents that have fields `"document_set": "a"` and `"document_set": "b"`.

These documents also have nested documents, lets say they look like this:

`[{ "fruit": "apple" }, { "fruit": "orange": }, { "fruit": "pear" }]`

I'd like to run a nested terms aggregation that gets me all the terms that ONLY exist in documents with `"document_set": "b"` and NOT in documents with `"document_set": "a"`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in the recent versions of ElasticSearch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue. I used a combination of `bucket_selector` sub-aggs and `filter` aggregations under my `terms` aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You must use mapping configuration for this subattributes as nested. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: Yes, they are nested fields. I am also aware of nested aggregations. What I'm trying to determine is how to filter out terms in the nested aggregation that exist in document set A and NOT in document set B.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this using aggregation filters or scripts. Sorry, I don't think I ever needed something like that.